# Running TFS queries from C# replacing the @Today Variable

Tags: tfs

I´m writing an extension to TFS that can run queries. As I have seen, before running the query  with the TFS API, all defined variables **must be replaced**.

I have looked at the default TFS variables [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286638.aspx#qvariables) and I can understand all except for **@Today** variable.

The main problem with the **@Today** variable is that you can add operators to it like:

[Source].[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate] = @today - 7

Do I need to replace the variable with the current date (and time?) and **let the query engine do the math**, or should I do the math **before** passing it to the query engine?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to replace `@Today` with anything, you can just run the query "as is".

For example running the following in [Linqpad](http://linqpad.net):

```
using (var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(CollectionAddress)))
{
    tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
    var server = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

    server
    .Query("select * from WorkItems where System.CreatedDate > @today - 1")
    .Cast<WorkItem>()
    .Select(wi => new { wi.Id, wi.CreatedDate, })
    .Dump(); //This is a http://LinqPad.net extension method.
}
```

Returns all the work items logged in my TFS Collection in since this morning.

The Work Item Query Language (WIQL) parser must take care of these things for you.

Comment: Sorry maybe I ddin't explain well, what I´m trying tu run is a LinkQuery. When running a LinkQuery with the Query method from WorkItemStore, this error occurs: TF248021: You have specified a query string that is not valid when you use the query method for a flat list of work items. You cannot specify a parameterized query or a query string for linked work items with the query method you specified.

Comment: So I need to run the query from the Query object, using RunLinkQuery method. That method, does not replace any variable.